# jquery append not working for creating html table

Tags: jquery, json

representation of my json data from arraList

```
var data = [{"analystNo":"","batch_name":"","can":"","curator":"kandasamy",
  "curator_status":"Available","current_login":"","qc":"",
  "qc_status":"","role":"","tan":"17264639U","worker":""},{"analystNo":"","batch_name":"","can":"","curator":"bramma",
 "curator_status":"Available","current_login":"","qc":"",
 "qc_status":"","role":"","tan":"17580309X","worker":""},{"analystNo":"","batch_name":"","can":"","curator":"abc",
 "curator_status":"Available","current_login":"","qc":"abc",
 "qc_status":"Available","role":"","tan":"17671633K","worker":""}]
```

jquery

```
var insert="";

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    insert += "<tr><td>"+data[i].tan+"</td><td>"+data[i].curator+"</td><td>"+data[i].curator_status+"</td><td>"+data[i].qc+"</td><td>"+data[i].qc_status+"</td></tr>" ;
}
alert(insert);
$('#tableID').append(insert);
```

inside html body

```
<table id='tableID' border="2">
<table>
```

i tested this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rpmH9/32/) but not working.
i think i miss something some where.

Comment: Change framework to jQuery on the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the framework dropdown on the left pane from mootools to jquery 1.7.1.

Comment: I would like to have a check box in each row at the 1st column which has the value of the existing 1st column. so i can send this as a struts2 form submit. how to do this?

Comment: add this in insert string after tr <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='"+data[i].tan+"' /></td>

Comment: its working and here I got another problem. `json1=new JSONArray(); json1.addAll(allocationList);` this is how I have created JSON. but I was unable to get it in my jquery success part why? and it goes to error part. my action class is returning success only.

Comment: and this is the jquery I have used to read json [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Xs4wu/)

Comment: Problem Solved!!! I used struts2-json-plugin, with some edition in struts.xml and so I dont need to convert any thng to json.